# Sqlite group by date get latest row value for that date

Tags: sqlite

Let's take for example this select:

```
Select date, sum(field1), max(field2)
 from table
group by date
order by date
```

Let's also say that in my table for each date I have 2-3 rows, so:

```
|   date   | field1 | field2  | 
-------------------------------
|01-01-2017| 4      | 34      |
|01-01-2017| 5      | 37      |
|01-01-2017| 3      | 33      |
|01-02-2017| 15     | 41      |
|01-02-2017| 13     | 39      |
```

My above select will return

```
|   date   | field1 | field2  | 
|01-01-2017| 12     | 37      |
|01-02-2017| 28     | 41      |
```

I want that for each date to obtain for field2 the last inserted value, so
33 for first date and 39 for the second one.

Any simple way of obtaining my result? Would simply removing the `max` for field2 work and the query would take the last value? 
I am using Sqlite on android if it matters.

LE: table also has id auto increment field as primary key.

Comment: What defines "latest" row? is there an id column?

Answer (score 3):

A table in RDBMS is an unordered set of rows. You'll have to define what "latest" row means.

Assuming there is an auto incrementing id column in your table based on which you decide what "latest" row is (i.e. the one with max id):

```
select date,
    sum(field1),
    (
        select field2
        from your_table t2
        where t.date = t2.date
        order by id desc limit 1
        ) as field2
from table t
group by date
order by date
```

Comment: Indeed, there's a id field... but what about the sum(field1)?